# Retrofit2 - Is possible to loop @Part of retrofit?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an issue with retrofit, the back-end only can use only @Mutilpart, i try use @PartMap map: HashMap<String, RequestBody> but still don't work. is possible to loop or another solution please help.

```
@Multipart
@POST("orders/total")
suspend fun orderList(
    @Part("Order[0][product_id]") product_id: RequestBody ,
    @Part("Order[0][quantity_id]") quantity_id: RequestBody ,
    @Part("Order[1][product_id]") product_id2: RequestBody ,
    @Part("Order[1][quantity_id]") quantity_id2: RequestBody ,
): Response<OrderModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending in a list

```
 @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> products
```

Comment: did you mean add each @Part into MultipartBody.Part and make it to list??